# Can I use cin inside a function call mult(); to allow the user to input 2 ints?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void mult ();

int main() {


    cout << "Please enter two integers: ";

   mult();

}

void mult(int a, int b){

    int ans = a * b;
    cout << "The answer is: " << ans << "." << endl;

}
```

Comment: Yes you can. But you should not take a and b as input parameter. You should declare them in function and get value from user. But its better to get the value from user in main and then send the values as parameter to function mult

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@imran is correct. As he said, you can pass arguments after taking inputs or you can take inputs in mult() functions by declaring variables there itself.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void mult ();

int main() {


mult();

}

void mult(){
int a,b;
cout << "Please enter two integers: ";
cin>>a;
cin>>b;
int ans = a * b;
cout << "The answer is: " << ans << "." << endl;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can. But you should not take a and b as input parameter. You should declare them in function and get value from user. But its better to get the value from user in main and then send the values as parameter to function mult like code below

There are few errors also in your code. You are defining `mult(int a,int b)` with parameters a an b but in declaration there are no parameters. Similarly in calling function you are not sending parameter values in the function. Correct code is as follow

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void mult (int a,int b);

int main() {

int a=0,b=0;
    cout << "Please enter two integers: ";
cin>>a;
cin>>b;
   mult(a,b);

}

void mult(int a, int b){

    int ans = a * b;
    cout << "The answer is: " << ans << "." << endl;

}
```